# autocomplete change css select using keyboard(arrow key)

Tags: css, jquery-autocomplete

I try to change the css when a user selects a result using the keyboard (arrow key).

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a:hover, .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a:focus, .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a:active {
    background:#ff8a00!important;
    color:#000;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

However, this css only takes effect with a mouse event.

[image]

Comment: do you have online demo ?

Comment: @Mohsen i have created one..http://jsfiddle.net/RDj4Z/2/

Comment: sorry but this code is not working on my program..please suggest somthing...only mouse event code is working..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RDj4Z/3/)**

**The CSS:**

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    background: #ff8a00;
    border: none;
    color:#000;
    border-radius:0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: sorry but this code is not working on my program..please suggest somthing...only mouse event code is working..

Answer (score 3):

try this :

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/RDj4Z/4/)

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus{
    background: #ff8a00!important;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```